# Extract nested tags with other text data as string in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract data.
Here is the specific part of the html-

```
     <div class="readable">

        <span id="freeTextContainer2123443890291117716">I write because I need to. <br>I review because I want to. 
    <br>I pay taxes because I have to. 
    <br><br>If you want to follow me, my username is @colleenhoover pretty much everywhere except my email, which is colleenhooverbooks@gmail.com
    <br><br>Founder of 
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.thebookwormbox.com" rel="nofollow">www.thebookwormbox.com</a> 
<br><br></span>

    </div>
```

I want output like this-

```
    I write because I need to.
    I review because I want to.
    I pay taxes because I have to.

    If you want to follow me, my username is @colleenhoover pretty much everywhere except my email, which is colleenhooverbooks@gmail.com 
Founder of www.thebookwormbox.com
```

I am trying this-

```
aboutauthor=response.xpath('//div[@id="aboutAuthor"]/div[@class="bigBoxBody"]/div[@class="bigBoxContent containerWithHeaderContent"]/div[@class="readable"]/span[1]/text()').extract() if len(response.xpath('//div[@id="aboutAuthor"]/div[@class="bigBoxBody"]/div[@class="bigBoxContent containerWithHeaderContent"]/div[@class="readable"]/span')) == 1 else  response.xpath('//div[@id="aboutAuthor"]/div[@class="bigBoxBody"]/div[@class="bigBoxContent containerWithHeaderContent"]/div[@class="readable"]/span[2]/text()').extract()
    print aboutauthor
```

And get the output-

```
[u'I write because I need to. ', u'I review because I want to. ', u'I pay taxes
because I have to. ', u'If you want to follow me, my username is @colleenhoover
pretty much everywhere except my email, which is colleenhooverbooks@gmail.com',
u'Founder of ', u' ']
```

What i do so that i get `www.thebookwormbox.com` with the output ?

Comment: you can use xpath with `//text()` and will get all the children's text content

Comment: thanks it works :)

Comment: glad it helps. I have put up my comment as an answer so we can close this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, you can use xpath with `//text()` to get all the children's text content.